# How to display different content to users in one email message

Tags: email, html-email

Our software system is designed to automatically send out emails for certain triggers (ie - order entered, invoice printed, etc).  Email format is HTML. An email can go to both employees and external users.

A feature request has come in to add some text and a hyperlink to the bottom of our emails. However this should only be visible to our employees, not to external users. We do *not* want to send two copies of each email (internal & external).

Our employees are all using some version of Outlook. We have no control over the email client used by our external users.

Is it possible to have the content of an email message change based on which user is reading the email?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution could be done whilst sending the emails.

For example you would have a database of email recipients. Add in a flag in the database to say whether they are a employee or not.

When you get to sending time, check for this flag and add on some extra html for this user.

This way normal users and employees appear to get "different" emails.